# jQuery drag-drop display div name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I need help with one extra add-on for my script.
After I have drag and dropped item, it prints out: dropped.
Is there a way to print it as class item names?
Like:
If I'd drag Item1 it would print out Item 1
and so one with item2, item3, item4, item5 and so on.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dragdrop.js"></script>

<div id="xx" class="out">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div class="item" name="item1">Item1</div>
<div class="item" name="item2">Item2</div>
```

### Item3

```
$(function() {
        $(".item").draggable({
                revert: true
        });
        $("#xx").droppable({
                tolerance: 'touch',
                over: function() {
                       $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
                },
                out: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
                },
                drop: function() {
                    $( this ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
                        $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
                }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this to happen?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfZc/2/)

```
drop: function(e, ui) {
     $( this ).find( "p" ).html('Dropped ' + ui.draggable.attr('name'));
     $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'd want this:

```
        drop: function() {
            $( this ).find( "p" ).html( $( this ).attr("class") );
            $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
        }
```